# SQL: How to group records, when they have different types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I do not know if I might be over-thinking this task. But I know I need some help. I have to modify a query in order to combine/sum those records that have multiple payment types for the same TransConfirmID.

The data below shows the first three records with the same TransConfirmID, but 2 different payment types. These records should have their payment amount summed up, and the payment type should be 'MULTI'.

The other records are various of the same TransConfirmID but with the same Payment Type for all 'ACH',  these records do not need to be summed up/combined, they can stay separated, they do not need to be grouped.

Is this a change I can get help to complete?

I am including a bit of sample data, and the query as I have it so far.

Data

```
AcctNumber  PaymentAmount   InitiationDate  SourceType  InvoiceNumber   PaymentType TransConfirmID
80924401229 -41.09          12/17/2019      PRPONL      NULL            CASH        1072667
80924401229 1600            12/17/2019      PRPONL      NULL            CASH        1072667
80924401229 2400            12/17/2019      PRPONL      NULL            ACH         1072667
70919228936 32.39           12/12/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34676067987
70919228093 2086.69         12/12/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34676067987
70826415014 4003.87         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34728080729
70824306182 8819.61         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34728080729
70913350587 259.54          12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34733928441
70913349150 5952.72         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34733928441
70922346155 259.54          12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34737135402
70922345404 9225.62         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34737135402
```

SQL Query

```
SELECT 
    RIGHT('0000000000000000' + AccountNumber, 16) AS AcctNumber
,   PaymentAmount
,   RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(MM, InitiationDate)), 2) + '/' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(dd, InitiationDate)), 2) + '/' + RIGHT(DATEPART(yyyy, InitiationDate), 4) AS InitiationDate
,   PropertyTaxHeader.SourceType AS SourceType
,   InvoiceNumber
,   LTRIM(RTRIM(PaymentType)) AS PaymentType
,   TransConfirmID
FROM 
    PropertyTaxDetail
INNER JOIN PropertyTaxHeader
ON PropertyTaxDetail.HeaderID = PropertyTaxHeader.id
WHERE   
    PropertyTaxHeader.STATUS = 'Active'
    PaymentStatus NOT IN ('RETN', 'RFND', 'RETURNED', 'REFUNDED')   
ORDER BY TransConfirmID
```

DESIRED OUTPUT (based on the sample data, this affects only the 3 first rows really)

```
AcctNumber  PaymentAmount   InitiationDate  SourceType  InvoiceNumber   PaymentType TransConfirmID
80924401229 3958.91         12/17/2019      PRPONL      NULL            MULTI       1072667
70919228936 32.39           12/12/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34676067987
70919228093 2086.69         12/12/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34676067987
70826415014 4003.87         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34728080729
70824306182 8819.61         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34728080729
70913350587 259.54          12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34733928441
70913349150 5952.72         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34733928441
70922346155 259.54          12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34737135402
70922345404 9225.62         12/13/2019      PRPKUB      NULL            ACH         34737135402
```

Thank you in advance for your help, and/or for reading this question.

Best regards.

Comment: So, what are the expected results for what you have here?

Comment: So really what you seem to be saying is you want to group by acctnumber instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The data below shows the first three records with the same TransConfirmID, but 2 different payment types. These records should have their payment amount summed up, and the payment type should be 'MULTI'.

If you `GROUP BY TransConfirmID` then you could say in the `SELECT` area:

```
CASE WHEN MIN(PaymentType) <> MAX(PaymentType) THEN 'MULTI' ELSE MIN(PaymentType) END as PaymentType
```

If PaymentType will ever be null, consider how you want to handle those. This code ignores NULLs, when working out if a MULTI  should be shown. If the values are only "CASH/NULL" and this should be a multi, use COALESCE to give the null a value that will never appear in the column:

```
CASE WHEN MIN(COALESCE(PaymentType, 'xxx')) <> MAX(PaymentType) THEN 'MULTI' ELSE MIN(PaymentType) END as PaymentType
```

> The other records are various of the same TransConfirmID but with the same Payment Type for all 'ACH', these records do not need to be summed up/combined, they can stay separated, they do not need to be grouped.

You've used language like "can" and "not need" rather than a hard rule of "must/shouldn't" so I assume that grouping by only `TransConfirmID` is acceptable, because if you do so then these things WILL become combined; you imply that this is OK. If you want them separated for sure, it looks like you should consider grouping by `AcctNumber`instead

Alternatively, to answer the question asked in the title - "How to group records, when they have different types", you can use a `CASE WHEN` do convert the different types into the same thing. Here is an example:

```
  SELECT
    Country,
    CASE PaymentType 
      WHEN 'CASH' THEN 'Untraceable'
      WHEN 'Bitcoin' THEN 'Untraceable'
      WHEN 'Visa' THEN 'Traceable'
      WHEN 'Mastercard' THEN 'Traceable'
    END as Traceability,
    SUM(Amount) as SumAmount
  FROM
    data
  GROUP BY
    Country,
    CASE PaymentType 
      WHEN 'CASH' THEN 'Untraceable'
      WHEN 'Bitcoin' THEN 'Untraceable'
      WHEN 'Visa' THEN 'Traceable'
      WHEN 'Mastercard' THEN 'Traceable'
    END
```

Rather than getting sum totals for cash/bitcoin/visa/mastercard (4 rows) this query produces 2 rows, with different values for payment types rolled up into a single value

If you have a lot of values to roll up consider adding a table that maps the hundreds of values for `paymenttype` to the various (same) `traceability` values and join it in, then group on the table columns of the joined table